# PostgreSQL ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.5"

Tags: linux, postgresql, gis, postgis

I've got a database with postgis installed, but it doesn't work anymore:

```
# SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.5": No such file or directory
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT public.postgis_lib_version()"
PL/pgSQL function postgis_full_version() line 26 at SQL statement
```

I found other answers which suggested running `ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;`, so I did, but it has no effect:

```
my_db=# ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;
NOTICE:  version "2.5.4" of extension "postgis" is already installed
ALTER EXTENSION
my_db=# 
my_db=# SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.5": No such file or directory
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT public.postgis_lib_version()"
PL/pgSQL function postgis_full_version() line 26 at SQL statement
```

Does anybody have any idea on how to solve this?

(I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 with Posrgresql version 12.3. and I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04, which I *think is when this started to be a problem)

[EDIT]

I searched in apt, and found this package which I didn't have installed yet: `postgresql-12-postgis-2.5`. So after installing that (`sudo apt install postgresql-12-postgis-2.5`) I restarted postgresql (`sudo service postgresql restart`) and tried again, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you check if the mentioned directory exists and if yes which what are the privileges (try to use  `pg_config | grep ^PKGLIBDIR` to get `libdir` full path).

Comment: @pifor - The result of `pg_config | grep ^PKGLIBDIR` is  `PKGLIBDIR = /usr/lib/postgresql/12/lib`. There's a lot of `.so` files in that directory, but nothing resembling `postgis-2.5` or `postgis`. Btw: I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 19.10 (which I think had postgres 11) to Ubuntu 20.04 (which now runs postgres 12). Could that have anything to do with it? I checked `/usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/` and in there there's also nothing that resembles `postgis`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how Ubuntu upgrade can impact PostgreSQL ( Iknow more CentOS). Did you create yourself the PG cluster in version 12 or did Ubunto upgrade do it ?

Comment: @pifor - I didn't do anything. Ubuntu did the whole upgrade.

Comment: I don't think that Ubuntu installs Postgis by default in a existing database. For PG 11: how has Postgis been installed ? Did you install it ? Did you run pg_restore from a source database that had Postgis installed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to post this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation for that. I had a very similar problem and explained in detail how I solved if over [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364790/postgresql-12-3-postgis-3-0-could-not-access-file-libdir-postgis-2-4-no/364818#364818). I hope this also helps you.

Answer (score 1):

It happened the same to me, after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.

Usually a postgresql major upgrade do not replace the previous version, because the dabatase has to be dumped and restored. The new version is installed alongside the old one, and at the new server is assigned a different port. Is up to the user to migrate the old database to the new version.

In my case, the upgrade, for some reason, removed the postgis-2.5 library in the previous postgresql version, leaving a broken postgis installation in the old database (and no installation in the new one, of course.)

It's easy to be confused and connect to the wrong server; at least, I was easly confused and so received the same error message even after having installed postgis for the new postgresql version. I discovered the problem checking pg_lsclusters and understanding which server was listening on which port.

Comment: Running `pg_lsclusters` indeed shows me two versions of postgresql running, version 11 on the default port 5432 and version 12 on port 5433. So that is good to know. But how did you use this knowledge to solve the issue? Did you uninstall version 11? And what did you do after that?

Comment: The procedure would be dumping the old database (pg_dumpall; using the version 11 of the utility) and restore it on the new one (pg_restore; using the version 12 version of the utility.) It's better explained in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/upgrading.html. Of course you need to connect on their respective ports. I'm afraid you have to have postgis correctly installed on both the source and the target database. Now I think you have installed it on version 12 and broken on version 11. I don't know how to further help you in repairing this.

Comment: If, like me, you are lucky enough to have another copy of the database on another computer, you can skip the dump and simply get rid of the old installation and get the new version listening on port 5432. Then restore from wathever working database you have.